# HD burned or if it was an error??? - How to check or know if can recoverd?

Tags: partitioning, grub2, system-installation, hard-drive, restore

The HD already had some badblocks and operated between 9 to 20 gb free.
Total space is 500gb.

Working perfectly with no problems

1.Yesterday he made a noise. It looked like you were scratching.
2.And crashed the screen.
3.I restarted the computer. And it worked for a while longer, until it crashed again.
4. Then it presented an error of not finding grub or ubuntu.
Error message delivary by bios. And not grub or ubuntu.

[image: Now-HD Display]

Now it appears in the disk list. But without much information. Like size and partition.

1.How do I know that the HD has burned? Or is it a partitioning problem?

2.If not burned. How can I recover the data? What commands.??

2.1 It's probably complex. First Resolve partitioning. Then think about data. I don't know any steps. ??

- The name of the hd also appears in the bios, is ok. But cant boot.
- And now it is connected by a usb sata adapter. And name is also recognized.

how to recover data from partition unable to mount?

sudo fdisk -l, blkid, lsblk - Return the new disk. Damage disk not in the list.

> > > sudo hwinfo --block --short - Show the damage disk.

/dev/sdb Exists.

But how to mount? Or how to recovery?

[image: hwinfo --block --short]

update:

```
sudo dmesg | grep 'sdb'
[    1.953441] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[    1.953457] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    1.953460] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.953485] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.004916] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  374.935097] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#10 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  374.935102] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#10 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  374.935106] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#10 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  374.935110] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#10 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[  374.935117] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[  375.063274] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[  375.063285] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  375.063292] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  375.063301] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#23 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[  375.063315] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
```

Comment: Since you have nothing to loose, and if you some tools open the HDD. The big round things are the platters. Your readheads, located in the arm, run against them. That is what made the noise. If they are stuck to the platters, move the platters counterclockwise. So they get unstuck. Mount the lid and try the disk. MAYBE you can save some data. NO GUARANTEES WHATSOEVER. That is why backups are so important. If it is really dead, you can hang the platters on some fishingline against flies and mosquitoes.

Comment: @JoepieEs No, you **never** open a HDD! OP probably had a head crash. Replace the drive and restore from backups.

Comment: @heynnema I have opened over 50 HDD's and was able to restore more than 30 TB.

Comment: I want to recover. Without lose. Then I discard the HD. // There is nothing that can be done at the code level???? @heynnema

Comment: I don't have the money to send the HD for recovery. They would know how to change the PCR. @JoepieEs

Comment: When I plug it into the power via the adapter.
I feel him turning. Without noise. @Heynnema

Comment: @LuizBrzDeveloper How old is the drive... more than 10 years old? I wouldn't even try to recover anything from it. Replace the drive. Do you have backups?

Comment: @JoepieEs HDDs are assembled in a clean-room environment. As soon as you open one up, you've compromised it, and any dust/dirt that gets in there can cause a head crash. Not at all recommended.

Comment: HD burned? Is it a Partition problem, superblock? Is there anything that can be done at the code level?

Comment: @LuizBrzDeveloper For the third or forth time: NO!

Comment: @heynnema I know. It cost me a small fortune to have my place build.

Comment: @JoepieEs i Will open the HD. Some new tips?